# Scripting in Linux and AWS CLI (command line interface)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a newb to Linux and AWS and I'm trying to figure out what should be a simple task. I have an instance of Amazon Linux running in EC2 and I'm trying to write a script that will start some new instances (same AMI). The script (called my_script) is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh                    
ec2-describe-instances
ec2-run-instances ami-b66ed3de -t t2.micro -k my-key-pair -g my_security_group
```

Whenever I try to run it, I get the error message:

./my_script: line 3: ec2-describe-instances: command not found

./my_script: line 4: ec2-run-instances: command not found

These commands work when I manually enter them in command line but not when I try to make a script containing them. I have tried fiddling around with the first line that says which interpreter to use, to no avail. Any input is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using commands in a script will not work, because the script is not run in the same environment as your current login. Try including the full paths to ec2-describe-instances and ec2-run-instances.
To find the full path, I believe you use the 'which' command in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I solved the issue by exporting the home directory at the beginning of the  script. In my case, I added the following.

**export HOME=/root**